# ionic 2 - how to work *ngIf with async function

Tags: ionic2, angular2-template, angular2-services

I create shopping cart and implement `hasExist()` method in cart service like this :

```
hasExist(product){
    let result=this.myCart.filter(item=>{
                return item.id==product.id;
             });
    return result.length!=0;
}
```

and use in template like this :

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let p of products">
 <ion-col col-3>        
      <ion-icon name="checkmark"  *ngIf="hasExist(p)" (click)="removeFromCart(p)"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="cart"  *ngIf="!hasExist(p)" (click)="addToCart(p)"></ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

and above code work very well but for share `cart array` in application I want use Storage like this :

```
async hasExist(product){
     this.myCart=await this.storage.get('cart');
     let result=this.myCart.filter(item=>{
                    return item.id==product.id;
                });
      return result.length!=0;
}
```

and use async pipeline in template for work with async method :

```
*ngIf="hasExist(p) | async"
```

but this way not working , my problem is how to work `*ngIf` with async function or another way to share cart array in application

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a plunker?